# JavaScript: Which way to create a new object type

Tags: javascript, object

I'm writing some JS at the moment but I'm not shure how to create a object in JS... On many sites i found many answers but which one should be use? For the first, I'm thinking there is no different. But i hope some of you can tell me more.

Here the three ways:

```
// Way 1
var SomeObject = {
    foo: "bar",
    bar: "foo",
    someMethod: function() {
        //code
    }
};

// Way 2
var SomeObject = function() {
    var self = this;

    this.foo = "bar";
    this.bar = "foo";

    this.someMethod = function() {
        //code
    }
}


// Way 3
var SomeObject = function() {
    var self = this;

    this.foo = "bar";
    this.bar = "foo";
}

SomeObject.prototype.someMethod = function() {
    //Code
}
```

Comment: `var obj = {}` or `var obj = new Object()` to give you some more possibilities

Comment: [MDN Working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).

Answer (score 2):

The three are different:

The first object has property `foo`, while way 2 and 3 have not. The latter are constructors that can make objects that have the `foo` property.

Ways 2 and 3 are also different: way 2 is a constructor that delivers objects with the `someMethod` method, while way 3 doesn't. Way 3 will define that method one level up -- on the prototype.

```
Way | constructor | instance has 
    |             | own someMethod
----+-------------+---------------
 1  |    no       |    yes
 2  |    yes      |    yes
 3  |    yes      |    no
```

#### What to choose?

When you only need one object instance, a singleton, then way 1 is what you would probably do. As soon as you need more than one, way 1 is not advisable.

If your methods have lots of code, then way 3 is almost certainly what you would go for: you want to avoid to recreate that function for every object instance. On the other hand there is a slight overhead if a method is not defined on the object itself, but on the prototype. That having been said, JavaScript optimises code and might eliminate both these issues in so doing. But way 3 is the most OOP way to do it.

The downside of way 3 is that you don't have access to private members, such as `self`. If its code relies on `this`, then care must be taken that these methods are called on instances of that prototype (or are explicitly bound to such), or the result may be unexpected.

Comment: So if I'm using the third way and I have two objects from Type SomeObject and the method someMethod can access to `self.foo`. And it will only affect the first object if I'm calling `objOne.someMethod()`? If yes, I will use the third way. And if its better to create  `this.me = this` instead of `var me = this`? I read that its a good way to create a self reference and use them in my methods because I could not be shure where `this` is refer to.

Comment: Like I wrote, in way 3 you cannot access `self` as it is a private member. So that is not possible. The object (`this`) that `someMethod` will act on is determined by the context of your call. Defining `this.me = this` does not help to avoid the `this` peculiarities, because you need `this` to access `me` then. If you have issues in getting `this` right, then way 3 will give you headaches. But if you have a good understanding of how `this` works, you can do anything with way 3.

Comment: Or just use Factory? This way you avoid problems down the road?

Comment: mmh damn, so maybe way 3 is not the best. For an example I have a move method which move an object by changing `x` and `y` and both are private.

Comment: Indeed, if `x` and `y` are private then you need to define methods on the object (not the prototype) to expose them, else you cannot access them via way 3. Way 2 will probably work best for you.

Answer (score 2):

The first way is called an object literal. The second and third ways are the same, and called function objects. In JavaScript functions are objects, and way 2,3 above are only different in their implementation of the someMethod() method, not in the object definition/implementation. You can also use var newObj = Object.create(Object.prototype) where newObj will inherit the Object.prototype. What is the best . . . Douglas Crockford says that Object literal declaration is the best because its more readable and compact.

Also, maybe you already know this, but you only need to create var self = this if you are nesting functions.